# Buckminster can't resolve org.eclipse.fx.javafx

Tags: equinox, efxclipse, buckminster

I was about to switch our build process from efxclipse 1.2.0 and eclipse *juno* to efxclipse 2.2.0 and *mars*. Before i switsched everyhting worked fine. Now after switching, buckminster complains that is can't resolve `org.eclipse.fx.javafx`.

The error is the following

```
org.eclipse.fx.javafx:osgi.bundle: No provider was found that could resolve the request
ERROR   [0003] : No suitable provider for component org.eclipse.fx.javafx:osgi.bundle was found in resourceMap file:/jenkins/jobs/XXX/workspace/XXX/buckminster.rmap
  ERROR   [0003] : No suitable provider for component org.eclipse.fx.javafx:osgi.bundle was found in searchPath local
    ERROR   [0003] : Resolution attempt ended with exception: Provider local(/jenkins/jobs/XXX/workspace/org.eclipse.fx.javafx): Missing CSpec source required by component type osgi.bundle
      ERROR   Provider local(/jenkins/jobs/XXX/workspace/org.eclipse.fx.javafx): Missing CSpec source required by component type osgi.bundleorg.eclipse.buckminster.core.ctype.MissingCSpecSourceException: Provider local(/jenkins/jobs/XXX/workspace/org.eclipse.fx.javafx): Missing CSpec source required by component type osgi.bundle
    at org.eclipse.buckminster.pde.cspecgen.bundle.BundleBuilder.parsePluginModelBase(BundleBuilder.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.buckminster.pde.cspecgen.bundle.BundleBuilder.parseFile(BundleBuilder.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.buckminster.pde.cspecgen.PDEBuilder.build(PDEBuilder.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.buckminster.core.ctype.AbstractComponentType.getResolution(AbstractComponentType.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.buckminster.core.ctype.AbstractComponentType.getResolution(AbstractComponentType.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.buckminster.core.rmap.model.ResourceMap.resolve(ResourceMap.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.buckminster.core.rmap.model.ResourceMap.resolve(ResourceMap.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.buckminster.core.resolver.ResourceMapResolver.innerResolve(ResourceMapResolver.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.buckminster.core.resolver.ResolverNodeWithJob.resolve(ResolverNodeWithJob.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.buckminster.core.resolver.ResolverNodeWithJob.run(ResolverNodeWithJob.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.buckminster.core.resolver.ResolverNodeWithJob$NodeResolutionJob.run(ResolverNodeWithJob.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

my target file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?pde version="3.8"?><target name="GUI Target" sequenceNumber="52">
<locations>
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.eclipse.fx.target.feature.feature.group" version="2.2.0.201512110704"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/runtime-released/2.2.0/site/"/>
</location>
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.sdk.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars"/>
</location>
</locations>
<includeBundles>
<plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher"/>
<plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.source"/>
<plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64"/>
</includeBundles>
</target>
```

and my rmap file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rm:rmap xmlns:bc="http://www.eclipse.org/buckminster/Common-1.0" xmlns:rm="http://www.eclipse.org/buckminster/RMap-1.0">
  <rm:locator pattern="^*" searchPathRef="local"/>
  <rm:searchPath name="local">
    <rm:provider componentTypes="eclipse.feature,osgi.bundle" readerType="local">
      <rm:uri format="{0}/{1}">
        <bc:propertyRef key="workspace.root"/>
        <bc:propertyRef key="buckminster.component"/>
      </rm:uri>
    </rm:provider>
  </rm:searchPath>
</rm:rmap>
```

So far I understand the problem, but I don't know how to tell buckminster how to resolve the missing package.

Answer (score 0):

resolving your target file, there is no `org.eclipse.fx.javafx` bundle.

[image]

You need to add the following to the target file, this will add the required bundles:

```
<unit id="org.eclipse.fx.core.feature.feature.group" version="2.2.0.201512110704"/>
```

[image]